# How to debug APNS on iphone from xcode

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications

My iPhone app is able to register for APNS remote notifications when I run it via an adhoc distribution. So I know that my adhoc provisioning profile is correct.

But I'd really to debug the app from xCode, runnin on my iPhone. In that case, I know that the app will use the APNS sandbox, which is fine. But when running in this mode, when the app calls registerForRemoteNotificationTypes, it gets the dreaded error "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application".

I assume that I should be using my developer code signing certificate when debugging the app on the iPhone from xCode. Is that correct? What stupid configuration thing I am missing that is causing the error?

Answer (score 3):

To be able to debug the application your server APNS should be configured with the Developer APNS certificated instead of the Distribution APNS certificate.

Because on Debug you're signing the application with the Developer certificate.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application - error is because, APNS is not enabled on your development provisioning profile.

To make sure your provisioning profile is APS enabled - Open your XXXXX.mobileprovision in text edit & search 'aps-environment'. You should be able to see something like below.

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>development</string>
```

Comment: Warning to anyone who thinks changing the string to `production` will help. Changing that string **doesn't** do anything. You have to build in release to access the production APNs environment.